# How to check which process is running?

Tags: c, fork, parent-child

Say I used fork twice to get two child processes. Then, I want to execute the 3 processes (including the parent) differently depending on the process is running. How will this be done in c language?
Will the following works:
Say PID1 is the process id for child 1 and similarly PID2 for child 2, then:
I first created the two child using:

```
    pid1 = fork();
    if(pid1 == 0){
       PID1=getpid();
    }
    if(pid1 > 0){
       pid2 = fork();
       if(pid2 > 0){
          printf("\nParent ProcessL %d\n",getpid());
       }
       else if(pid2 == 0){
          PID2=getpid();
       }
     }
-----------------------------------------------------
further down in my code:

    while(/*true for a certain time*/){
       if (PID1==getpid()){
           //execute the code for child 1
       } else if (PID2==getpid()){
           // execute code for child 2
       } else {
           // execute the code for the parent
    }
```

by the way, do processes run randomly or they run in order (fixed time for each)?

Comment: About the last question, they do not have specific order. It all depends on your processors scheduler. It will decide when and how much time to give to process.Scheduler uses algorithm to decide. Most famous ones: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/operating_system/os_process_scheduling_algorithms.htm

Answer (score 0):

It won't because the `pid` returned by `fork()` in the child is `0`.

The simplest way to achieve your goal is to simply branch off right after each `fork()`.

```
pit_t PID1, PID2;
if(0>(PID1=fork()) {/*handle error*/}
if(!PID1) _exit(code_for_child1());

if(0>(PID2=fork()) {/*handle error*/}
if(!PID2) _exit(code_for_child2());

/*continue the parent's work*/
```

Comment: Yes, that can work. But why? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle